# Is it possible to have a Hausdorff dimension less than the topological dimension?

Tags: dimension-theory-analysis, hausdorff-measure

"Normal" geometric shapes have Hausdorff dimensions equal to their topological dimensions. Mandelbrot defined fractals as shapes that have a Hausdorff dimension greater than their topological dimension. Is there a class of shapes that have a Hausdorff dimension less than their topological dimension, or is this impossible? If there is such a shape, what are common examples of them?   If this is impossible, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shapes you are asking about do not exist. The reason is:

**Theorem.** (Sznirelman) For every metric space $X$, the Hausdorff dimension of $X$ is $\ge$ the covering dimension of $X$.

See for instance section VII.2 of

W.Hurewicz, H.Wallman, [Dimension Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691627746), Princeton University Press.

Comment: I will wear the down-vote on this answer as a badge of honor.

Comment: I just saw this (you cited it in a recent comment elsewhere), and thought I'd mention that I've had downvotes on selected answers (more than once), and I think I've even had more downvotes than upvotes on a selected answer, but I don't feel up to looking for any now, and besides, over time I've tended to get upvotes on these "problematic" answers when others have later come across them, so even if I looked now, it's likely that the more extreme such cases are no longer all that extreme.